# Computer restarts every few minutes when inactive

Tags: windows-7

Hello my computer is restarting every 5-10 minutes when it's inactive. Nothing crashes, I have no errors it just restarts over and over again.

Is there something that I should look into? I have no problems when I'm constantly working on moving mouse on the screen at least.

Comment: Does it do a proper restart (windows closing all programs etc), or switches off and back on abruptly?

Comment: Try disabling your screen saver or changing the time before it comes on - also in your power management, increase the times/turn off shutdown/hybernate and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you have any external USB devices attached, like a USB hard drive?

Comment: What model computer do you have? desktop? Laptop?

Comment: Check in c:\windows\minidumps and see if you have any BSOD logs (match up the date and time in the log to close to when the computer randomly shut down).  Could be a BSOD and the log would point you in the right direction of what caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an old installation or suspect any malware may have compromised your OS, consider running `sfc /scannow` from the command line with elevated privileges. Doing so, you will be able to repair possible corrupt system files.

Notes:

- Run a tool of your preference to verify no malware is running
- Your Windows 7 installation media may be requested during the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

it's Hot in There
Sometimes this can be caused by an overheating situation. Itunes, RealPlayer, Windows Media player,etc. require a lot of processing power to decompress and decode music files, which can cause the processor or hard drive to get hot.
Memory Fails Me...
If you determine that overheating is not the problem, the most likely suspect is bad memory.